# UIbutton don't change background inside IBAction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

I have 3 custom UIButtons with text, and when user click on one of buttons I check if answer is right. If it is right I want set button background green, if not red. Then I want to show next question automatic, after a little delay (he need a bit time to see if previous answer was right).

The problem is that UIbutton  background don't change inside IBAction, but it change inside setWordAndAnswers function. And I don't have any idea why it happens(((

Here is the code:

```
-(void)setWordAndAnswers{
if([[currentCollection allWards] count]>0){
    int randCard =arc4random_uniform([[currentCollection allWards] count]-1);
    currentWord=[[currentCollection allWards]objectAtIndex:randCard];
    tvMainWord.text=[currentWord originalWord];

    int wrightAnser =arc4random_uniform(2);
    for(int i=0;i[answers count];i++){
        [[answers objectAtIndex:i]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        if(i==wrightAnser){
            [[answers objectAtIndex:i] 
            setTitle:[currentWord wordTranslate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else{
             [[answers objectAtIndex:i] 
             setTitle:[self getRandomAnswer] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
- (IBAction)onClickCheckAnswer:(id)sender {
if(!isGameRunning)
    return;
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if([[sender title]isEqual:[currentWord wordTranslate]]){
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
else{
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
[button setNeedsDisplay];
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.3f];
[self setWordAndAnswers];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the UIButton is of type custom like this:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Additionally why are you calling `NSThread` sleep?, if you want to delay execution of setwordandanswers I would use `performSelector:afterDelay`, or if you have a dependency then use `NSOperationQueue addDependecy`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The problem was in NSThread sleep I used performSelector:afterDelay and now it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sender itself, instead of creating a new button in your method..
And change the type of sender to `(UIButton *)` ( Only change if it does not work with (id))

`- (IBAction)onClickCheckAnswer:(UIButton *)sender`

```
  if([[sender title]isEqual:[currentWord wordTranslate]]){
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}

    else{
        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
```

:)

Please, do give a feedback..

Comment: The problem was in  NSThread sleep, but thank you for nice way to change button background color)

Answer (score 0):

I've grabbed the following lines from your given code:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if([[sender title]isEqual:[currentWord wordTranslate]]){
```

Change this to following:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if([[button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[currentWord wordTranslate]]){
```

Then, I believe it should work.